# Does backup data go through the backup exec server?

Tags: backupexec

I'm reading over the Backup Exec 2012 manual and planning our deployment.

One thing I haven't figured out is if the actual data always goes through the backup exec server to the storage, or if it goes (or can go, if setup properly) directly to the storage like it does now in Backup Exec 2010.

eg, I have 3 sites:

Site A has the majority of our servers, including what will be the backup exec server, as well as a NAS on the same LAN to store backups.

Site B has 3-4 servers, and a NAS for storing it's backups.

Site C has 2 servers - each backs up to a second hard drive in the other server daily, then offsite backups are taken weekly over a VPN to site A.

All 3 sites are connected through VPNs, but over relatively slow links.  If I setup a backup to go from a server at site B, to the NAS at site B, is the bulk of the data going to stay on Site B's LAN, or is it going to cross the VPN TWICE!?!, once from the server to backup exec, and again from backup exec to the NAS?

Backup Exec 2010 does it directly from the server to the NAS, but after reading the ~1500 page manual cover to cover I still can't quite figure out how 2012 does it.

Comment: Symantec pre-sales can usually handle such questions.  Have you spoken to them?

Comment: No I haven't, but that's the next place I planned on looking for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Symantec's technical support, all backup data does go through the backup exec server.

So you will need to either have sufficient bandwidth to handle that (client side deduplication MAY help), or have a local backup exec server.